# Why I can't use ToShortDateString on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: I can see here...]

I used like this `d.PODate.ToString()` to display(see image) I can see it using inspect element... I want to display only date not a time and when I try to use `d.PODate.ToString("d")` it gave me error like this `Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL`
and same to `d.PODate.ToShortDateString()` got error like this `Method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' has no supported translation to SQL.`

**EDIT**

this is my GET method

```
[HttpGet]
public Models.SysDataTablePager Get()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);

    string sEcho = nvc["sEcho"].ToString();
    int iDisplayStart = Convert.ToInt32(nvc["iDisplayStart"]);
    string sSearch = nvc["sSearch"].ToString();
    int iSortCol = Convert.ToInt32(nvc["iSortCol_0"]);
    string sSortDir = nvc["sSortDir_0"].ToString();

    var BranchId = Convert.ToInt32(((wfmis.Global)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).CurrentBranchId);

    var Count = db.TrnPurchaseOrders.Where(d => d.MstUser.Id == secure.GetCurrentUser() && 
    d.MstBranch.Id == BranchId).Count();

    var PurchaseOrders = from d in db.TrnPurchaseOrders
                         where d.MstBranch.Id == BranchId &&
                               d.MstBranch.MstUser.Id == secure.GetCurrentUser()
                         select new Models.TrnPurchaseOrder
                         {
                             Id = d.Id,
                             PeriodId = d.PeriodId,
                             Period = d.MstPeriod.Period,
                             BranchId = d.BranchId,
                             Branch = d.MstBranch.Branch,
                             PONumber = d.PONumber,
                             POManualNumber = d.POManualNumber,
                             //PODate = d.PODate.ToShortDateString(),
                             PODate = d.PODate.ToShortDateString(), //<------
                             SupplierId = d.SupplierId,
                             Supplier = d.MstArticle.Article,
                             TermId = d.TermId,
                             Term = d.MstTerm.Term,
                             RequestNumber = d.RequestNumber,
                             //DateNeeded = d.DateNeeded.ToShortDateString(),
                             DateNeeded = d.DateNeeded.ToString(), //<------
                             Particulars = d.Particulars,
                             RequestedById = d.RequestedById == null ? 0 :
                                             d.RequestedById.Value,
                             RequestedBy = d.MstUser.FullName,
                             IsClosed = d.IsClosed,
                             PreparedById = d.PreparedById,
                             PreparedBy = d.MstUser.FullName,
                             CheckedById = d.CheckedById,
                             CheckedBy = d.MstUser1.FullName,
                             ApprovedById = d.ApprovedById,
                             ApprovedBy = d.MstUser2.FullName,
                             IsLocked = d.IsLocked,
                             CreatedById = d.CreatedById,
                             CreatedBy = d.MstUser3.FullName,
                             //CreatedDateTime = d.CreatedDateTime.ToShortDateString(),
                             CreatedDateTime = d.CreatedDateTime.ToString(),
                             UpdatedById = d.UpdatedById,
                             UpdatedBy = d.MstUser4.FullName,
                             //UpdatedDateTime = d.UpdatedDateTime.ToShortDateString()
                             UpdatedDateTime = d.UpdatedDateTime.ToString()
                         };

    switch (iSortCol)
    {
        case 2:
            if (sSortDir == "asc") PurchaseOrders = PurchaseOrders.OrderBy(d => d.PODate).Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(10);
            else PurchaseOrders = PurchaseOrders.OrderByDescending(d => d.PONumber).Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(10);
            break;
        case 3:
            if (sSortDir == "asc") PurchaseOrders = PurchaseOrders.OrderBy(d => d.PONumber).Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(10);
            else PurchaseOrders = PurchaseOrders.OrderByDescending(d => d.PODate).Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(10);
            break;
        case 4:
            if (sSortDir == "asc") PurchaseOrders = PurchaseOrders.OrderBy(d => d.Supplier).Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(10);
            else PurchaseOrders = PurchaseOrders.OrderByDescending(d => d.Supplier).Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(10);
            break;
        default:
            PurchaseOrders = PurchaseOrders.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(10);
            break;
    }

    var PurchaseOrderPaged = new Models.SysDataTablePager();

    PurchaseOrderPaged.sEcho = sEcho;
    PurchaseOrderPaged.iTotalRecords = Count;
    PurchaseOrderPaged.iTotalDisplayRecords = Count;
    PurchaseOrderPaged.TrnPurchaseOrderData = PurchaseOrders.ToList();

    return PurchaseOrderPaged;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I got this on my DateTime on my database...
[image]

Comment: Please reformat your code..

Comment: Please provide the LINQ query that makes troubles. ASP.NET is not related to your issue.

Comment: The problem is not related to ASP.NET. The problem is that your linq query gets translated into SQL. And in SQL, there is no mapping defined for the `ToShortDateString()` method. You can add a mapping function yourself, which then uses SQL syntax to trim the date you are fetching from your database into a string.

Comment: General suggestion: Don't convert from specific types (date, numeric, …) until you actually render the content for the user (ie. in your view). This has two benefits: 1. locales (for output) only need to be handled in that one place; 2. any processing can be done in the proper type rather than processing a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d` is coming from the database; it does not exist as a .NET object at this point.  You are asking LINQ-to-SQL to do the .ToShortDateString() in the database, for which there is no conversion function.

If you select the `d` values first and use `.ToList()` at the end of the query, you can then create your models with the string formatting functions.

E.g.:

```
// original db query, still returns IQueryable.
var dbPurchaseOrders = from d in db.TrnPurchaseOrders
                         where d.MstBranch.Id == BranchId &&
                               d.MstBranch.MstUser.Id == secure.GetCurrentUser();

// change db query to local, in-memory object list
var localPurchaseOrders = PurchaseOrders.ToList();

// change the local db.TrnPurchaseOrders objects into your Models.TrnPurchaseOrder objects.
// kept the d variable because I'm too lazy to change all lines of your code.
var PurchaseOrders = from d in localPurchaseOrders
                         select new Models.TrnPurchaseOrder
                         {
                             Id = d.Id,
                             PeriodId = d.PeriodId,
                             Period = d.MstPeriod.Period,
                             BranchId = d.BranchId,
                             Branch = d.MstBranch.Branch,
                             PONumber = d.PONumber,
                             POManualNumber = d.POManualNumber,
                             //PODate = d.PODate.ToShortDateString(),
                             PODate = d.PODate.ToShortDateString(), //<------
                             SupplierId = d.SupplierId,
                             Supplier = d.MstArticle.Article,
                             TermId = d.TermId,
                             Term = d.MstTerm.Term,
                             RequestNumber = d.RequestNumber,
                             //DateNeeded = d.DateNeeded.ToShortDateString(),
                             DateNeeded = d.DateNeeded.ToString(), //<------
                             Particulars = d.Particulars,
                             RequestedById = d.RequestedById == null ? 0 : d.RequestedById.Value,
                             RequestedBy = d.MstUser.FullName,
                             IsClosed = d.IsClosed,
                             PreparedById = d.PreparedById,
                             PreparedBy = d.MstUser.FullName,
                             CheckedById = d.CheckedById,
                             CheckedBy = d.MstUser1.FullName,
                             ApprovedById = d.ApprovedById,
                             ApprovedBy = d.MstUser2.FullName,
                             IsLocked = d.IsLocked,
                             CreatedById = d.CreatedById,
                             CreatedBy = d.MstUser3.FullName,
                             //CreatedDateTime = d.CreatedDateTime.ToShortDateString(),
                             CreatedDateTime = d.CreatedDateTime.ToString(),
                             UpdatedById = d.UpdatedById,
                             UpdatedBy = d.MstUser4.FullName,
                             //UpdatedDateTime = d.UpdatedDateTime.ToShortDateString()
                             UpdatedDateTime = d.UpdatedDateTime.ToString()
                         };
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Also there are lots of such questions and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163183/linq-to-sql-peculiarities. Jerald, do not forget about google search!

Answer (score -1):

Try This.

```
CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Parse(d.CreatedDateTime.ToString()).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: I got this error `The best overload method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Add To.String() in d.CreatedDateTime.ToString(). I have also edited my code. check.

Comment: This is not the answer until the op has local objects to work with.